# JQuery Colorbox with JQuery Validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, colorbox

I am using JQuery validation on a form, and it works well, but when i put the form in "colorbox", the validation does not work anymore!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function validateform(){
        $("#edit_contact_form").validate({
            rules : {
                "phone" : {
                    required : true,
                    number : true,
                    minlength : 7
                }
            },
            submitHandler : function(form) {
                alert("form submitted");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    $.colorbox({html:$("#edit_contact_div").html()});

    $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
        validateform();
    });

    });
```

I also tried onComplete event!

Comment: maybe your binding order is out, ie you are binding to a non-existent element so colorbox form doesn't exist when you add event handler

Comment: Also show the relevant HTML markup of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
function validateform(){
    $("#edit_contact_form").validate({ ... });
}

$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    validateform();
});
```

The `.validate()` method is only the *initialization* method of the plugin, not the method to test the form.  Furthermore, `.validate()` is only supposed to be called *once* for this initialization and any subsequent calls are always ignored.  So calling it multiple times by placing it inside another function or event handler is usually very glitchy or totally broken.

Call `.validate()` immediately after the form's HTML is constructed, typically on DOM ready.

The plugin will also ignore hidden fields automatically.  Since your form's HTML appears to be `hidden` until it's needed, set the `ignore` option to disable this behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#edit_contact_form").validate({
        ignore: [], // allow validation of hidden fields
        // your rules, options, and callbacks
    });

    $.colorbox({html:$("#edit_contact_div").html()});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("body").on('click','cbox_complete', function(){
    validateform();
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    validateform();
});
```